# How to fix webdriver.Chrome error: "SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

But getting this error:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 87.0.4280
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 87.0.4280

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-5-0be288b55e31>", line 1, in <module>
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 34, in install
  driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\manager.py", line 21, in _get_driver_path
  driver_version = driver.get_version()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 40, in get_version
  return self.get_latest_release_version()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 63, in get_latest_release_version
  resp = requests.get(f"{self._latest_release_url}_{self.browser_version}")
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
  return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
  raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_87.0.4280 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```